# Mockito test which callback called

Tags: android, mockito, junit4

i want to test when user login fail in mockito

my interface

```
public interface OnLoginFinishListener {
  void onFail();

  void onSuccess();
}
```

my LoginInteractor class

```
public class LoginInteractor {

  public void validateCredentialsAsync(final String email, final String password, final OnLoginFinishListener listener) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(email.equals("sample@email.com") && password.equals("123456")){
                listener.onSuccess();
            }else {
                listener.onFail();
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

how to write a test for login fail case, thank you

Comment: you wish to test `onFail()` method or fail scenario? what have you tried for fail scenario?

Comment: @SabirKhan i'm learnning test framework  in android, so i want to test fail scenario, thank you

Answer (score 2):

may be you want mock your OnLoginFinishListener and verify if it called

```
            LoginInteractor in = new LoginInteractor();
            OnLoginFinishListener mockListner = mock(OnLoginFinishListener.class);
            doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            }).when(mockListner).onFail();
            doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

                @Override
                public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            }).when(mockListner).onSuccess();
            in.validateCredentialsAsync("sample@email.com","wrong",mockListner);
            verify(mockListner,times(1)).onFail();
            verify(mockListner,never()).onSuccess();
```

Comment: sorry, i have problem when run your test `Wanted but not invoked:
onLoginFinishListener.onFail();
-> at com.android.droidtemplate.login.LoginPresenterTest.testLoginFail(LoginPresenterTest.java:74)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Comment: `line 74: verify(mockListner, times(1)).onFail();//fail should be called`

Comment: @meowmeo, Yes, i failed notice the runnable. You need to use the doAnswer(). i have updated the answer

Comment: so sorry i have error: `Wanted but not invoked:
onLoginFinishListener.onFail();
-> at com.android.droidtemplate.login.LoginPresenterTest.testLoginFail(LoginPresenterTest.java:83)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock`  , line 83: `verify(mockListner,times(1)).onFail();`

Comment: are you starting the thread properly in your Handler class. Probably you are missing/forgetting to call the runnable at, postDelayed(Runnable r, int x){
       r.run();
}